# "thetaLength" parameter seems not working in my program

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I just wrote a single program to generate some circle geometries randomly. But the circles generated are all incomplete. I tried to set the parameter for CircleGeometry to 2Pi but it didn't work either. Can someone please tell me what's wrong? Here's the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Procedural Geometry Generation</title>
  </head>

  <style>
  body {margin: 0;}
  canvas {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
  </style>

  <body>
    <script src="js/three.js"> </script>
    <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"> </script>

    <script>

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var ratio = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80,ratio,0.1,1000);

    camera.position.set(0,0,20);
    camera.lookAt(0,0,1);

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var circles = [];
                  
    function NegOrPos() {
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*(11-1) + 1);
        if (n <= 5)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    function ClearScene() {
       for (let i = scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if(scene.children[i].type == "Mesh")
            scene.remove(scene.children[i]);
    }

    function CreateScene() {
        var num = Math.random()*(20 - 2) + 2;
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            var material_circle = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
            material_circle.color = new THREE.Color(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random());
            material_circle.wireframe = true;
            var rad = Math.random()*(5 - 0.2) + 0.2;
            var seg = Math.random()*(65 - 3) + 3;
            var geometry_circle = new THREE.CircleGeometry(rad, seg);
            circles[i] = new THREE.Mesh(geometry_circle, material_circle);
            circles[i].translateX(NegOrPos()*(Math.random()*(25 - 3) + 3));
            circles[i].translateY(NegOrPos()*(Math.random()*(13 - 3) + 3));
            //circles[i].rotation.y += Math.random()*(10 - 1) + 1;
            //circles[i].rotation.z += Math.random()*(10 - 1) + 1;
            scene.add(circles[i]);
        }
    }

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

    var MyUpdateLoop = function() {
        ClearScene();
        CreateScene();
        renderer.render(scene,camera);

        controls.update();

        requestAnimationFrame(MyUpdateLoop);
    };

    requestAnimationFrame(MyUpdateLoop);

    var MyResize = function() {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        renderer.setSize(width,height);
        camera.aspect = width/height;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', MyResize);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, is there a way to slow down the animation or generation speed? I think it is related to my monitor fresh rate but maybe I was wrong.

Comment: which one is the thetaLength parameter?

Comment: **But the circles generated are all incomplete** Then they are probably "arcs" on radius. Check your numbers.

Comment: `new THREE.CircleGeometry(rad, seg);` default for the next two arguments is `0, 2*PI` - so, you should be getting full circles radius 4.8 to 5 with random 3 to 61 triangles - though, `seg` needs to be an Integer - perhaps that's the issue - try `var seg = parseInt(Math.random()*(65 - 3)) + 3;`